# Lifecycle aware delegate in Compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have an immutable delegate I need to use in compose. I can't do it like

```
val abc by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf() }
```

because of the error: `NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized`

I also can't use it in the viewModel because of its context dependent status. So, I can move the delegate outside of the scope:

```
private val selectedMarker by lazy { BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE) }

@Composable
fun MapView(){
    Marker(icon = selectedMarker)
}
```

but I need it to be lifecycle aware. What are the optimal practices for that?